# Upgrading Scipy 0.10 on Red Hat Linux Server 5.5 (Tikanga)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, redhat, yum

I am trying to upgrade from scipy 0.10 to 0.13 on Red Hat Linux 5.5.  I was able to install and upgrade numpy to 1.8.0 through pip, but when I try to use pip to upgrade scipy 0.10 it tells me that it cannot find BLAS or LAPACK libraries.

I have tried using yum to install scipy but it thinks everything is up-to-date because the repo has an old version of scipy 0.5 in it.

What is the best way to upgrade scipy on Red Hat Linux 5.5

Comment: Have seen this: http://www.scipy.org/install.html

Comment: Yes, but I cannot get yum to pull any new repo other than scipy 0.05 which is far too old.